# Meteor JS HTTP get profile pic with Facebook API v2.5 - server side

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I've tried with these Meteor `HTTP.get` methods in the server side:

```
HTTP.get(`http://graph.facebook.com/${fbUserId}/picture?callback=?`, {
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
}, function(data){
    console.log(data); // [Error: failed [400]]
});

HTTP.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${fbUserId}/picture`, {
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
}, function(data){
    console.log(data);  // null
});
```

However, this works in the client side with jQuery:

```
$.getJSON(`http://graph.facebook.com/${fbUserId}/picture?callback=?`, function(data){
     console.log(data); // {url: 'http://img-url...'}
});
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
@Ethaan answer worked (with a few additions):

```
function _fetchUserFacebookThumbnail(fbId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        HTTP.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/${fbId}/picture/?redirect=0&type=square`, function(error, data){
           resolve(data['data']);
        });
    });
}
```

According to FB Developers docs, the `?redirect=0` query requests a JSON object instead of the image itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` on the second one because there is not error, so that means the second example work, try with `error`, `data` instead of just `error`.

Also if you only want to get the picuture you can just link to this.

`facebookPicture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userFacebookId + "/picture/?type=large";`

btw, mexican developer over here head ups =p.